# Lua, getting x and y coordinates and color

Tags: colors, lua, coordinates

I'm not sure how advance a subject this is, but I am wondering if there's a code that can do the following:

1. Scan each pixel in an image.
2. Get the Red, green, and blue values of each pixel.
3. Assign the x and y position's and color to a table/variable, which ever is the most efficient (And possible).
4. Use this data in a separate script/function to make something happen based on the RGB values.

So, can this be done in Lua? And if not, is there a language that can attach to Lua like C++ that can? Or am I not able to have Lua at all? I've done some searching but can't find an answer. Not even sure if this is possible, doesn't seem to have popped up anywhere.

Comment: Are you looking for someone to write that code for you? Or what, exactly? It's not clear what kind of answer you're looking for here.

Comment: My apologies for that, I'm asking if there are any features in lua for this, and by features I mean things like os.time, math.random, that kind of stuff.

Comment: I need to head off now, I'll be back in the morning to answer any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely possible with libraries. See [this page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LibrariesAndBindings) for a list. If you do not know which one to choose, start with [imlib2](http://asbradbury.org/projects/lua-imlib2/doc/).